# jquery function select custom attribute from select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the custom attribute values from the select box.  It is triggered by a checkbox click which I already have working.  I can get the name and value pairs just fine.  I want get the custom attributes (therapy) (strength) (weight) and (obstacle) from the option value lines. is this possible?

**select box**

```
<option value="2220" therapy="1" strength="1" weight="0" obstacle="0">Supine Calf/Hamstring Stretch</option>
<option value="1415" therapy="0" strength="0" weight="0" obstacle="0">Sitting Chair Twist</option>
<option value="1412" therapy="0" strength="0" weight="0" obstacle="0">Static Abductor Presses</option>
```

**jQuery**

```
// exercise list filter category         
jQuery.fn.filterByCategory = function(checkbox) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var select = this;
            var optioner = [];

            $(checkbox).bind('click', function() {

                var optioner = $(select).empty().scrollTop(0).data('options');

                var index=0;
                $.each(optioner, function(i) {

                    var option = optioner[i];
                    var option_text = option.text;
                    var option_value = parseInt(option.value);

                        $(select).append(
                           $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
                        );

                    index++;
                }); 
            });
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the selected , like this:

```
var $select = $('#mySelectBox');
var option = $('option:selected', $select).attr('mytag');
```

Answer (score 0):

That is how to get selected option attribute:

```
$('select').find(':selected').attr('weight')
```

Answer (score 0):

Get selected option and use `attr` function to get the attribute:

```
$("select").find(":selected").attr("therapy")
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wjsDL/)